# Set UID for Dexterity type

Tags: plone, dexterity

I'm migrating content from Archetypes to Dexterity and I need the new items to have the same UID as the old ones.

On Archetypes items I can call context._setUID('my-uid'). Is there something similar for Dexterity?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For Dexterity UUID values, the [`plone.uuid` package](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/plone.uuid) is used. `plone.uuid` simply stores the value in a attribute.

The following suffices to set a predetermined UUID on an existing Dexterity object `obj`:

```
from plone.uuid.interfaces import ATTRIBUTE_NAME

setattr(obj, ATTRIBUTE_NAME, uuid)
```

Comment: We should probably add a plone.uuid.interfaces.IMutableUUID adapter for Archetypes content so that that interface can be used for all content.